# Is it possible to shorten these doctrine queries?

Tags: doctrine

```
    $q_auctions = Doctrine_Query::create()
       ->select('COUNT(t.id) AS num_items')
       ->from('Auctions t')
       ->where('t.ends_at > NOW()');

    $q_auctions_upcoming = Doctrine_Query::create()
       ->select('COUNT(t.id) AS num_upcoming')
       ->from('Auctions t')
       ->where('t.starts_at > NOW()');

    $q_auctions_closed = Doctrine_Query::create()
       ->select('COUNT(t.id) AS num_closed')
       ->from('Auctions t')
       ->where('t.ends_at < NOW()');
```

I have these 3 very similar auctions in Doctrine, but I'm not sure wether I can shorten it somehow. I don't like so much repeating so maybe if someone could give me a tip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I wouldn't worry about having the three queries too much unless you're really trying to cut down the total number of queries for this page. Indexes on starts_at and ends_at might help speed things up but depends on the number of records in those tables.

The only thing that comes to mind right now would be to do a single query, return the start and end dates, and then parse those inside a PHP foreach loop into the three groups you need. This would drop the queries from 3 to 1 but add some PHP overhead. If you've got hundreds or thousands of auctions there, this might not be a good idea.

Comment: Actually no, max ~30 auctions on a page. Would it be better if i did it with PHP then?

Comment: @Tool: What's important is how many auctions there will ultimately be in the database because you would be returning start/end dates for *all* auctions to PHP. 30 is fine, but will there be 300 closed auctions after a year, 3000 after a few years, etc? Without knowing more about the app, I think I'd just keep the queries.